# Using matplotlib in python script to enable plotting in add-on

Tags: python, add-on, mathematics

i would like to create an add-on that can plot graphs using matplotlib inside the add on frame.
Does anyone have any experience  with using matplotlib or any other python lib in blender? 
Is it possible to plot the graph in an add-on frame?